# Storing large (~30k elements) float array in Java

Tags: java, android

What is the correct way to store large static arrays in Java?

I have three arrays of floats, each consisting of about 30000 elements that I need to access from my program. The contents of the arrays will not change.

Edit: I am currently not able to access the arrays from any Java program without splitting them up into relatively small (sub 1k elements) arrays, putting them in separate methods (each limited to 64KB of bytecode) and then merging them in the program. Which seems like an abysmal solution to me.

Comment: Are you looking to store them for the length of your program, or permanently?  For the first, an array is fine.  For the second, a database is probably the right answer (although a flat file could work as well for such simple data).

Comment: Permanently, they contains vectors for a 3d-model. I would prefer not bloating the program with a database driver as it seems overkill. Looking for the right type of flat file and loading procedure.

Comment: The database drivers are built into the Android framework.  But if you want a simple flat file for an array-  just write out each float as binary data, and then read it in as binary floats until EOF.  No need for anything fancy with simple data.

Comment: you will get a lot of out of memory exceptions i don't know but database will be your best choice here

Comment: Try `DataOutputStream`/`DataInputStream` for what Gabe is suggesting... But alternatively, using plain old serialization (with `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`) would be nearly as compact, and easier.

Comment: Sure, but writing the binary data to a file requires me to actually have the arrays accessible to my program first, though.

Comment: @Martin it requires you to have the data available to *a* program; and isn't it? It doesn't have to be the same program that reads it, just one that can write it in the known format.

Comment: @AndyTurner, well yes but the difficulty lies in getting the arrays to _a_ program. I would prefer not having to split it up into 30 methods due to the 64k method code size limitation in Java. :)

Comment: 3 arrays of 30_000 floats as primitives would be around 3MB - it that too much?

Comment: @Eugene, Too much for what? My problem right now is that i have no way of accessing these arrays from my/a java program.

Comment: i did not read the comments and that is not clear from the question at all

Comment: Sorry about that, sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a separate program that accepted the matrices on stdin and stored them in files. First row in each file is an integer representing the number of elements in the matrix, the following rows are the actual matrix elements. Not a pretty solution, but it got the job done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    float[] floatArray;
    int count = in.nextInt();
    float temp;
    int i = 0;
    floatArray = new float[count];
    while (in.hasNextFloat()) {
        temp = in.nextFloat();
        floatArray[i] = temp;
        i++;
        }
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("glockVert.arr"));
        outputStream.writeObject(floatArray);
}
```